# One Time Trial Use of Bitcoin?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

How do I get on and off Bitcoin as quickly as possible? Could someone please write a detailed tutorial on the 'How To' of using Bitcoin for one single transaction, just to get some experience. Please.

Comment: "Please write a detailed tutorial" is asking for quite a bit more than a question on this site is expected to do.

Comment: What is the point of that?  Just watch people use it on Youtube if you do not want to participate.

Comment: To easily get some coins you can go to an online "Bitcoin faucet" to receive a tiny amount of bitcoins which then you can spend however you like. Prior to that you must get a "wallet"... there are plenty of tutorials in the web that explain Bitcoin and its technology, how to get in, what to do, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bitcoin't testnet network if you just want to give it a go, instructions as well as some useful links can be found at: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Testnet

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the level you want to try Bitcoin on, [trybtc.com](http://trybtc.com) might offer just what you want. The website gives a cursory overview of how Bitcoin works, and then gives you a minuscule amount of bitcoins to send to a charity and share with a friend.